# How to insert (left or right) only one figure in a minpage

Tags: floats, minipage, emptypage

I have a odd number of figure (Karnaugh maps). And now the result is this:

[image: The results of my code]

I have written this code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$AB$][$CD$]
            \maxterms{4,12,1,5,13,6}
            \minterms{0,8,9,2}
            \indeterminants{3,7,14,11,15,10}

            \implicant{8}{10}
            \implicantcorner
        \end{karnaugh-map}
        \captionof{figure}{Segmento `e'.}
        \label{fig:k-map-e}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$AB$][$CD$]
            \maxterms{4,12,8,13}
            \minterms{0,1,5,9,2,6}
            \indeterminants{3,7,14,11,15,10}

            \implicant{0}{2}
            \implicant{2}{10}
            \implicant{1}{7}
            \implicantedge{1}{3}{9}{11}
        \end{karnaugh-map}
        \captionof{figure}{Segmento `f'.}
        \label{fig:k-map-f}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{karnaugh-map}[4][4][1][$AB$][$CD$]
            \maxterms{0,4,13}
            \minterms{12,8,1,5,9,2,6}
            \indeterminants{3,7,14,11,15,10}

            \implicant{2}{10}
            \implicant{1}{7}
            \implicant{8}{10}
            \implicantedge{12}{8}{14}{10}
        \end{karnaugh-map}
        \captionof{figure}{Segmento `g'.}
        \label{fig:k-map-g}
    \end{minipage}%

    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The question is: I would like that the last map appear on the left. I know that I can insert, in the last minpage, a figure of one pixel white, but I do not think that this is the best solution.

Thank's to all.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\centering` with `\raggedright`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to include a second, empty `minipage` in order to push the first one to the left, all the more so that this trick won’t work if the `minipage` is truly empty: you need to include at least a blank space in it, for example

```
\begin{minipage}
    \noindent\space\par
\end{minipage}
```

But, as we were saying, this is not necessary: it suffices to instruct TeX to set the contents of the `figure` environment ragged right, instead of centering them.

Here is a MWE; note that I’ve also eliminated some empty lines that yielded unwanted paragraph breaks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        First map.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        Second map.
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{First and second map}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        Third map.
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        Fourth map.
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{Third and fourth map}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp!]
    \raggedright
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        Fifth map.
    \end{minipage}%
    \caption{Fifth map}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of hte code]